# Not able to Add Solution to Subversion using Visual Studio 10 and AnkhSVN

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn, subversive

I am using tortoise SVN and created one folder named TestMVCApplication2 at D:/svn/ location.

[image]

2 ) Then I created repository as below

[image]

[image]

3) Then created one solution in Visual Studio 2010 named TestMVCApplication2 and add some pages and then tried to add project to subversion as below..

[image]

4) But I get error saying that "Please select valid location in repository to add to"

[image]

What wrong I am doing here..?

Comment: I know this is a late response, but curious if you had an actual subversion repository server? Like CollabNet Subversion Edge? Not sure you can get by without some kind of SVN server.

Comment: @steve you can access SVN repositories locally without any server at all via the file:// protocol. In this case the svn.exe acts as both client and server.